# Can I ask a question about what will I miss if I stop drinking milk? And what are other alternative food options to cover up that?

Tags: discussion, nutrition

Suppose you stop drinking milk. So you will miss protein and vitamin D.

I don't know much about other details. So I want to know if I stop drinking milk what important ingredients/vitamins I will miss that are important for normal physical health/fitness?

Another thing I want to know is alternatives. When I try to find resources about it online, all I find is almond milk, coconut milk etc. which are not available where I live. Even if some of those alternative milks are available, they are expensive for me.

So I'm looking for possible solid foods or more common foods. Maybe almonds may help. But I'm not sure.

Also, if I keep eating yoghurt in the same amount that I used to drink as milk, will it also cover up things I will miss by not drinking milk?

Again, I googled about it, and all I found articles like "why yoghurt is better than milk" etc. They didn't talk anything about if yoghurt can cover up necessary milk nutrition.

**Can I ask this question on main site?**

Comment: Eh, I'm lactose-intolerant so I can assure you that you don't cease to exist.

Comment: @C.Lange I understand. But you must be getting those essentials nutrients like Vitamin D, Calcium etc. from alternative foods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is a question that is off-topic for this site.

A common mistake is thinking that anything that pertains to a person who is seeking to improve their physical fitness is on-topic, but I appreciate that you ask here first to get a clarification.

The site is for questions that are primarily and directly about the actual activity of exercise. This includes the actual training itself, and to an extent, the direct preparations for a training session, and the post-workout regimen.

Similar on-topic questions could be

- is milk suitable as part of a pre-workout meal?
- is milk suitable as part of a post-workout meal?
- if I remove milk from my post-workout meal, what are the ideal substitutes?

Perhaps the last one could be worth asking?

Comment: As Alec says, pretty much off topic. Even the last suggestion is borderline. There have been a few attempts to get a nutrition site going, but they have all fallen short of even launching.

Comment: @Alec the last one - nope actually. As I can see, on topic questions rely some degree on work-out or physical activities. So my question won't fit at all as I am interested in general health and nutrition.

Comment: I will try reddit.